# Use multiple columns as unique identifier for mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with the following columns:

```
group_id
game_id
user_id
message
last_update
```

I want to make it so that no two rows can exist where the value of group_id for row x is equal to the value of group_id for row y AND the value of user_id for row x is also equal to the value of user_id for row y.

So, for example, let's say I insert the following following values:

```
group_id = 783
game_id = 34
user_id = 29237
message = none
last_update = 11233452
```

The above data, even if a mysql query tries to insert it, should not create a new row if a row already exists with the same combination of group_id and user_id. Is there a way to do this? Basically, I'm trying to get two columns to work together kind of like an unique index.

Comment: Is there any reason why group_id and user_id are not the primary keys for this table?

Comment: They are set as indices, but does being set to primary make a difference for trying to accomplish the task? If so, I can make them primary.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Yes, MySQL provides the ability to do this.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD UNIQUE KEY `my_unique_key` (`group_id`, `user_id`)
```

I don't know what you're using this table for, but it sounds like this unique key might be a strong candidate for primary key of the table. A primary key is automatically a unique key as well. If you decide to make it the primary key, then do the following instead:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`, `user_id`)
```

(If you receive an error message that there is already a primary key, then issue `ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP PRIMARY KEY` and then repeat the above command.)

**Edit:** In response to user comment

You cannot have multiple rows with identical non-`NULL` values for the columns covered by the unique key. So you cannot have two rows where `group_id = 0 AND user_id = 5`, for example. 0 is a value. But if you make one or both of the columns nullable, you **can** have multiple rows that are identical up to positioning of `NULL`s. So you could have two (or more) rows where `group_id IS NULL AND user_id = 1234`.

Proviso: The above is true for both commonly-used MySQL storage engines (MyISAM and InnoDB). MySQL does have storage engines in which `NULL` is regarded as a unique value, but you are probably not using them.

If you make one or both columns nullable, then your unique key cannot be the primary key - a primary key has to be on columns that are `NOT NULL`.

Let's suppose you had made this key your primary key and you now want to allow `NULL` in the `group_id` column. I don't know what datatype `group_id` is at the moment; I'll assume it's currently `INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`, but you will have to modify the below if it's not this. You would no longer be able to use this key as your primary key. Here is a command you could run to make the desired changes:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    MODIFY group_id INT UNSIGNED,
    ADD UNIQUE KEY `my_unique_key_with_nulls` (`group_id`, `user`)
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that the they only work together as a primary/unique key only if group_id != '0' ?

Comment: +1 you inspired me how to use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY, when there's no primary key, just two foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

well for this you can create composite key of group_id and user_id using any mysql editor like phpmyadmin or sqlyog, and mark it as unique index.